# Not being able to fetch data from sites in selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working with python, selenium. I'm typing a keyword which is then being searched on google. In the results section, I am trying to open the URLs one by one and storing the data of the p tag.

But in my script, it is storing data of only one site. Can anyone help on this to store the data of p tag of all the opened sites?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


"""
Taking input from user
"""

search_input = input("Input the keyword you want to search for:")
search_input = search_input.replace(' ', '+')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="E:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

for i in range(1):
    matched_elements = driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" +
                                     search_input + "&start=" + str(i))

print(driver.title)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

links_url = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='yuRUbf']/a[@href]")
links = []


for x in links_url:
    links.append(x.get_attribute('href'))
link_data = []
for new_url in links:
    print('new url : ', new_url)
    driver.get(new_url)
    link_data.append(driver.page_source)

"""
Getting the data from the site
"""

content = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "p")
for data in content:
    print(data.text)

driver.back()
driver.close()
```

Comment: Just indent content to match up with the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the edited answer, first I misunderstood your question:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


"""
Taking input from user
"""

search_input = input("Input the keyword you want to search for:")
search_input = search_input.replace(' ', '+')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="E:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

for i in range(1):
    matched_elements = driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" +
                                     search_input + "&start=" + str(i))

print(driver.title)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

links_url = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='yuRUbf']/a[@href]")
links = []


for x in links_url:
    links.append(x.get_attribute('href'))

link_data = []

for new_url in links:
    print('\nnew url : ', new_url)

    driver.get(new_url)

    #Getting the data from the site

    try:
        link = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "p")

        for p in link:
            print(p.get_attribute("innerText"))
    except:
        continue

driver.quit()
```

Comment: But still it is fetching data from one site. i want the data of p tag from every site opened.

Comment: @SahilSuri you did other mistakes too, I have edited my answer and modified your code. Please check. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey @MuhammadYousufNoor, I have added a new question regarding this same question can you look into it. i am new to this so making some errors while coding!!! Would be thankful!!!  This is the link - https://stackoverflow.com/q/66021250/13845032