# getting data from sites and making summary of it

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, summarization

Hi I was working on two different scripts one is getting data through selenium and one is getting summary of data. so Getting data from sites is working fine but when I am passing that data to do summary of the data, the data is not being passed in my summary. please let me know where i am making error and how to fix this. I am new to python selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize

"""
Taking input from user
"""

search_input = input("Input the keyword you want to search for:")
search_input = search_input.replace(' ', '+')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="E:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

for i in range(1):
    matched_elements = driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" +
                                     search_input + "&start=" + str(i))

print(driver.title)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

links_url = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='yuRUbf']/a[@href]")
links = []


for x in links_url:
    links.append(x.get_attribute('href'))

link_data = []

for new_url in links:
    # print('\nnew url : ', new_url)

    driver.get(new_url)

    #Getting the data from the site

    try:
        link = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "p")

        for p in link:
            datas = p.get_attribute("innerText")
            print(datas)
    except:
        continue


driver.quit()

#getting summary of data

print("\nOriginal text:")
print(datas)
textWordCount = len(datas.split())
print("The number of words in Original text are : " + str(textWordCount))


stopWords = set(stopwords.words("english"))
words = word_tokenize(datas)


freqTable = dict()
for word in words:
    word = word.lower()
    if word in stopWords:
        continue
    if word in freqTable:
        freqTable[word] += 1
    else:
        freqTable[word] = 1


sentences = sent_tokenize(datas)
sentenceValue = dict()

for sentence in sentences:
    for word, freq in freqTable.items():
        if word in sentence.lower():
            if sentence in sentenceValue:
                sentenceValue[sentence] += freq
            else:
                sentenceValue[sentence] = freq

sumValues = 0
for sentence in sentenceValue:
    sumValues += sentenceValue[sentence]

average = int(sumValues / len(sentenceValue))

summary = ''
for sentence in sentences:
    if (sentence in sentenceValue) and (sentenceValue[sentence] > (1.2 * average)):
        summary += " " + sentence
print("\nSummary:")
print(summary)
summaryWordCount = len(summary.split())
print("\nThe number of words in summary are : " + str(summaryWordCount))
```

Comment: that is a lot of code to ask us to review.  can you narrow down the part where the script fails, then show us what error messages you get

Comment: Till driver.quit it is working fine and showing all the data scraped. But after that when i am getting summary of data. It does no pass the whole datta to get summary of it. You can see after driver. quit when i am using print(datas) it is not printing the whole text.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with this line:

```
datas = p.get_attribute("innerText")
```

this rewrites the value of datas with each iteration of the loop.
I'm guessing that you are really wanting to append to a list, or expand a string with a space between words?